# Trouble with restarting java game

Tags: java

We've created a Maze game where the player needs to collects keys in a specific order to win. At the end of the game, if the player failed to collect keys in that specific order the player can choose to restart(press R) or quit(press Q) the game.

The problem is when the player chooses to restart, a new game pops up, yes, but the old or previous game is still running.

Here is the `Launcher` class:

```
public class Launcher {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

   Game game = new Game("DUNGEON ESCAPE", 500,500);
   game.start();

    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ThisMaze\\src\\OurMaze\\BGM.wav"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(inputStream);
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    Thread.sleep(10000000); 

}
```

Here is that code that checks if the player collected the right order of keys and calls the `WrondEndState` if the player is wrong (This is located in the `Inventory` class, separate from the `Launcher` and the `WrongEndState` class:

```
public void addItem(Item item){


    // R - 0    O - 1   Y - 2   G - 3   B - 4   I - 5   V - 6
            KeyQueue.add(item.getId()); 


            Iterator<Integer> kq = KeyQueue.iterator(); 

            if(KeyQueue.size() == 7){    
                while(kq.hasNext()){
                    if(! (BaseQueue.poll() == KeyQueue.poll()) )
                    {

                        State.setState(WrongEndState); 
                        break;
                    } else
                        State.setState(RightEndState);

                }
            }
```

And this is the part or the `WrondEndState` that checks what the player wants to do (restart or quit):

Inside the if-else in this class the `handler.getKeyManager().restart` 
the `.restart` is a key:

`restart = keys[KeyEvent.VK_R];`

And so is the `.exit` in `handler.getKeyManager().exit`:

`exit = keys[KeyEvent.VK_Q];`

```
public void tick(){

    if(handler.getKeyManager().restart)
       try {
            gameStart();

    } catch(Exception ioe){
           System.out.print("Error."); }
    if(handler.getKeyManager().exit)
        System.exit(0);
}
```

This is the `gameStart();` method the if-else code is calling:

```
  public void gameStart() throws Exception{
    Game game = new Game("DUNGEON ESCAPE", 500,500);
    game.start();

    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ThisMaze\\src\\OurMaze\\BGM.wav"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(inputStream);
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    Thread.sleep(10000000); // looping as long as this thread is alive  

     }
}
```

Please help and do tell if you need more of the code to help.

Comment: Honestly, I think you've added too much of your code here. Reading your question, it's a little hard debugging through so many lines of code. Could you please just include the code for starting the game, checking whether the user has ended in the WrongEndState, checking the user's input to either Restart or Qui,t and where you start a new game please?

Comment: Please tell if you need more or less of the code. Thanks Mr Pigeon.

Comment: `handler.getKeyManager().restart` is restart a method or a key? Also when the game ends how do you close it is important.

Comment: Also `Thread.sleep(10000000); // looping as long as this thread is alive  
` seems way too much. Whats the intention there?

Comment: You need to close the old game. So what is the code when the user wants to quit? I guess you can reuse some part here, e.g. dispose the GUI and stuff, but not exit the process, of course.

Comment: @nullpointer the restart is a key (`restart = keys[KeyEvent.VK_R];`). When the game ends. If the player is successful in collecting the right order of keys, that games says to "Press 'Enter' key to close" thus ends the game. Else, the player can choose whether to restart or quit (Press [R] or [Q]).

Comment: @LukeLee Yes,close the old game is what I need. I just don't know how to do it. When the user wants to quit? During the game or after collecting all keys? If during the game, the only thing the player can do to quit is close the window. If after the game, depends on the order of keys the player has collected. If player has collected right, the game will display "Press 'Enter' key to close". else, game will display "You are wrong, Press [R]- to restart / [Q] - to quit"

Comment: @nullpointer the `Thread.sleep(10000000);` is for the background music of the game.

Comment: So what happens when the user choose `Q`?

Comment: @LukeLee It will exit the game. `System.exit(0);`

Comment: on reset you create an other game instance and you start it. What do you expect? Store states at the beginning an reset them when you want, like health, time, score.. Don't create one more game.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, got caught up with an issue at work. What happens if you add `System.exit(0);` after you start a new game in the try block of the tick function? Does it close both instances, the old instance or the new instance of the game?

Comment: @eldo Yes, that is the problem. The code only calls for a new game and doesn't end the previous one that is running. I don't know what code to add/change to close that previous one.

Comment: @MrPigeon It didn't change anything. There's still the previous games/instances running. But when I close the game(by pressing 'Q' or exiting the window) they all close at once.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a `new Game` if you want it to restart. Thats uneccessary.

When the game starts a new game instance is created thats fine. Start called which is just fine. In a game there are several things, states, objects whaver they all have an inital state/value.

Lets say you have a game, all you have to do is runnig forward, jumping. There is a score and time spent whit the current run, player has positions and so on. If you die you want it to restart. You don't create an other game by `new Game` 
all you do is restoring everything to their initial state/value.

This fictianal games resetGame method would look like this:

```
private void resetGame(){
    player.x = 0; //assuming player starts at 0,0
    player.y = 0;
    score = 0;
    time = 0;
}
```

Find everything in your game that should be restore to its initial value on restart.

This is very simplified but I hope its understandable.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. I think I've found and changed every variable. But the game doesn't use those new variables. Could you please give an example of changing a variable, boolean and array to an value _from another class_ ?

Comment: @Wisteria Its hard to tell what should you do without seeing the actual code but you can access public field just simply like game.somePublicVariable = 0; or via getters and setters like game.setVariable(0); If you need a more specific answer consider asking an other question containing every game play relevant variables which should be reset.